# Remote host closed connection during handshake for SOAP Connection

Tags: java, ssl, curl

Am trying to connect to a SOAP Endpoint.

```
 public SOAPMessage getRequestObjectResponse(SOAPMessage message) {
    System.setProperty("https.protocols", "TLSv1");
    try {
        SOAPConnectionFactory soapConnectionFactory = SOAPConnectionFactory.newInstance();
        SOAPConnection soapConnection = soapConnectionFactory.createConnection();

        // Send SOAP Message to SOAP Server
        return soapConnection.call(message, config.getBaseUrl());
    } catch (SOAPException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(SOAPWebServiceTemplate.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Using the above I keep getting the following error below

> at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_191]
>   Caused by: com.sun.xml.messaging.saaj.SOAPExceptionImpl: Message send failed
>           at com.sun.xml.messaging.saaj.client.p2p.HttpSOAPConnection.post(HttpSOAPConnection.java:297) ~[saaj-impl-1.5.0.jar!/:na]
>           at com.sun.xml.messaging.saaj.client.p2p.HttpSOAPConnection.call(HttpSOAPConnection.java:160) ~[saaj-impl-1.5.0.jar!/:na]
>           ... 59 common frames omitted
>   Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Remote host closed connection during handshake
>           at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_191]
>           at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_191]
>           at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_191]
>           at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_191]
>           at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_191]
>           at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_191]
>           at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getOutputStream0(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_191]
>           at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getOutputStream(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_191]
>           at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_191]
>           at com.sun.xml.messaging.saaj.client.p2p.HttpSOAPConnection.post(HttpSOAPConnection.java:252) ~[saaj-impl-1.5.0.jar!/:na]
>           ... 60 common frames omitted
>   Caused by: java.io.EOFException: SSL peer shut down incorrectly
>           at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.read(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_191]
>           ... 70 common frames omitted

I did a `curl -v` and checked the urls' details using this [website ssllabs](https://www.ssllabs.com/)

Curl Info below

`* Expire in 0 ms for 6 (transfer 0x181648d20a0)
* Expire in 1 ms for 1 (transfer 0x181648d20a0)
* Expire in 2 ms for 1 (transfer 0x181648d20a0)
* Expire in 2 ms for 1 (transfer 0x181648d20a0)
* Expire in 3 ms for 1 (transfer 0x181648d20a0)
* Expire in 3 ms for 1 (transfer 0x181648d20a0)
* Expire in 5 ms for 1 (transfer 0x181648d20a0)
*   Trying some_ip ...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Expire in 200 ms for 4 (transfer 0x181648d20a0)
* Connected to url_not_disclosed (some_ip) port 443 (#0)
* ALPN, offering h2
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: C:\Users\Developer\Downloads\CURL\curl-7.64.0-win64-mingw\bin\curl-ca-bundle.crt
  CApath: none
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* OpenSSL SSL_connect: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL in connection to url_not_disclosed:443
* Closing connection 0
curl: (35) OpenSSL SSL_connect: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL in connection to url_not_disclosed:443`

Details from sslabs below

[image: ssl labs TLS Protocol detail for url]

Answer (score 0):

So SSL 3 is normally disabled in java 1.8 and all I add to do was enable it.

1. Go To your JAVA_HOME directory, go to JAVA_HOME\lib\security\
2. Open the java.security file with any text editor
3. Find the jdk.certpath.disabledAlgorithms in that file and comment it out